# Error in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

Anyone knows how to fix this ?
It works fine on my env (Me being the developer) and doesn't work on my colleagues machine who unzips the whole

Welcome to Grails null - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: C:\abc\products\grails-1.1

Base Directory: C:\abc\products\foo\bar
Running script C:\abc\products\grails-1.1\scripts\RunApp.groovy
Environment set to development
Application expects grails version [1.1], but GRAILS_HOME is version [null] - us
e the correct Grails version or run 'grails upgrade' if this Grails version is n
ewer than the version your application expects.

Some clarifications
1) There has been no Grails version change , either on my machine or my colleagues machine. In fact some of them are installing for the first time

2) Under C:\Documents and Settings\myfriend.grails I can see a folder called 'null'
I tried removing this folder - but it gets created he runs my application

3) The way I am giving him the release is- I unzip the whole folder and he unzips it
SO there are three steps
A_ grails create-app to create the APp
B_ Unzip my folder to replace the generated folder
C_ Grails run-app

Things are fine after the step A- but degenerate after Step C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

This was because I had added a file- build.properties
And since the file was there- it was expecting it to have certain properties defined in it

Once I renamed it to something else- it started to work

Answer (score 0):

It appears that his Grails installation is corrupted or not set up correctly.  I would have him reinstall a fresh copy of Grails - http://www.grails.org/Installation and try again.

The error that you are getting is telling us that the application that you are trying to run is identified as version 1.1 and I assume that this is correct.  The fact that Grails is not able to identify what version is installed makes me point to a corrupted or mis-configured Grails installation

If he types '`grails`' at the command line what does he see?